# Pandas replace/remove puncation from strings

Tags: pandas

What does this do in python?

```
 df['Name'].str.replace('\W', ' ')
 df['Name'].str.replace('_', ' ')
 df['Name'].str.replace('  ', ' ')
```

Does \W remove "=" from a string? I have a script and I'm trying to figure out where the "=", ",", and more get removed from my strings.

Can anyone explain what would remove this punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

The part of replacing with punctuation can also be performed using regex. In this, we replace all punctuation with an empty string using a certain regex

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate working of
# Removing punctuations in string
# Using regex
import re

# initializing string
test_str = "Gfg, is best : for ! Geeks ;"

# printing original string
print("The original string is : " + test_str)

# Removing punctuations in string
# Using regex
res = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', test_str)

# printing result
print("The string after punctuation filter : " + res)
```

> OR

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate working of
# Removing punctuations in string
# Using loop + punctuation string

# initializing string
test_str = "Gfg, is best : for ! Geeks ;"

# printing original string
print("The original string is : " + test_str)

# initializing punctuations string
punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''

# Removing punctuations in string
# Using loop + punctuation string
for ele in test_str:
    if ele in punc:
        test_str = test_str.replace(ele, "")

# printing result
print("The string after punctuation filter : " + test_str)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does `df['Name'].str.replace('\W', ' ')` actually do?

Answer (score 0):

\W (upper case W) matches any non-word character. This means not only "=" is replaced but any non-word character, e.g. "%","&","§","/",...